# Bot sends an empty message when I try to send a RichEmbed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot on discord.js. I'm having some trouble with RichEmbed. Here is the code:

```
if (command === "q") {
  const messageID = args[0];
  console.log("MSG id " + messageID);
  message.channel.fetchMessage(messageID).then(messagea => {
    const reportEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("Reports")
      .setColor("#F7E533")
      .addField("Message", messagea.content)
      .addField("Reported User", `@${messagea.author}`)
      .addField("Reported By", `${message.author} with ID: ${message.author.id}`)
      .addField("Time", message.createdAt);

    message.channel.send({
      embed: reportEmbed
    });
    console.log(reportEmbed);
    return;
  })
}
```

The result is this:

[image: The bot sends an empty message]

Console logs contain the embed requested, but it is not in the message it sends.
What I'm missing?

UPD
Every RichEmbed I try to send is empty. Could it be that my guild requires additional setup?

Comment: Does the message even exist?

Comment: Check that the bit has permissions to actually send embeds on your server @krege

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti Bot has Admin permissions.

Comment: @GillesHeinesch As I said 'console.log(reportEmbed);' show me the message. And even more, i did simple
    message.channel.send({embed: {
              color: 3447003,
              description: "A very simple Embed!"
        }});
with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in account preferences: discord require links preview to be enabled to show the embed. So choose: preview all links or disable embed.

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct by clicking the hollow arrow, making it green.

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti stackoverflow tells me I need to wait until tomorrow. I have to obey.